# Gmail sort or group by sender?

Tags: gmail

I am trying to cleanup my inbox. I have searched everywhere, and everyone is suggesting to create filters or search yourself which is totally impractical.

Is there any way in Gmail to sort or group emails by sender? Mailstorm online service seems to do that (allows grouping by sender, subject etc) but it is not free. Can this be achieved with Gmail itself?

Comment: How would sorting by sender help you clean your inbox?

Comment: Sorting put all senders together and I can easily make a choice of keeping or deleting emails from specific senders.

Comment: I see, well you can use a client like outlook or mail to sort (as stated in answer) or you can just search for the sender as you come across it (that's what I do). So if I see that I have an email from some mailing list I stopped reading, I'll click "filter messages like this" and then select all and archive/delete.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail only sorts by date descending. Obviously you can filter by lots of different things, including sender, using the search options, but that's going to be a little impractical if you just want to group all of your messages rather than seek out specific senders.

You'd need to use a third-party tool. Most email clients will let you do that. I've used [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) in the past, but most other email clients should do what you're looking for. It's just a question of getting them to talk to Gmail. (Which is outside the scope of this site.)